# i uninstalled meta mask from my android phone however i have failed to import the old account even though i know the 12 phrase

Tags: metamask

meta mask app was un installed from android phone. Upon re-installation, the app asks for a 12 phrase to import my account.  i have tried to import with the 12 word pass phrase but this has failed yet the 12 phrase is correct one. How can i restore my old account which has some ETH! please assist

Answer (score 0):

Once try to import your account on the Chrome Metamask extension. Hope it works this way.